# Adding ConsumerRebalanceListener to the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In a Spring Boot application I'm using a class annotated with @KafkaListener as a message listener. I want to add a ConsumerRebalanceLister to my application to manage cached data on a rebalance.

How do I add a ConsumerRebalanceListener to a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#rebalance-listeners) says that it should be set on a ContainerProperties object. It's not clear how to access that object in order to set it. Additionally, it looks like the [ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/v2.1.10.RELEASE/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java) throws away the rebalance listener since it creates a new ContainerProperties object when creating a listener container instance.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here, before [this commit](https://github.com/neilg/spring-kafka/commit/31541fe58e8b1265728301106027b250657aaeb2) there was a method to simply set the rebalance listener directly on the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider to use this method on the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`:

```
/**
 * Obtain the properties template for this factory - set properties as needed
 * and they will be copied to a final properties instance for the endpoint.
 * @return the properties.
 */
public ContainerProperties getContainerProperties() {
```

This is where you can add your `ConsumerRebalanceListener`. You `@Autowired` an auto-configured `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and perform the mentioned injection:

```
@Autowired
private ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory containerFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.containerFactory.getContainerProperties()
            .setConsumerRebalanceListener(myConsumerRebalanceListener());
}

@Bean
public ConsumerRebalanceListener myConsumerRebalanceListener() {
    return new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: Can @beans be removed? What is the use of placing them here?

Comment: Yes, if your `ConsumerRebalanceListener` implementation has not dependencies from beans in the Spring application context, then you may not use `@Bean` declaration on that method.