# Spring Kafka acknowledgment settings

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application where we are using spring Kafka in consumer section i have made enable.auto.commit to false and set my `listener ack-mode to manual_immediate`

I have concurrent consumers so after consuming the record I call acknowledgment.acknowledge() but here i still face the duplicate issue problem whenever rebalance happens other consumer start consuming the same message which is already consumed by one consumer. Any idea what magic is happening behind the scene.

Anyone know when using manual_immediate does it commit message by commitSync or commitAsync ? is there way we can change the behaviour to avoid duplicates record message reading. Is there a way we can use hybrid model in Spring Kafka

In spring boot Kafka is there a way we can see whenever a rebalance happen i can log it.

How to create rebalance if we want to do it for some testing purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you call `acknowledge` on the listener thread, it will use `commitSync()` by default; use the `syncCommits` container property to use async commits.

If you call it on a different thread, the commit is queued to be processed by the consumer thread as soon as possible.

Duplicates cannot be avoided if a forced rebalance takes place because your listener took too long to process the records received by the `poll()`.

You can increase `max.poll.interval.ms` and/or reduce `max.poll.records` to ensure you can process the records in time.

You can add a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` to the container properties to log rebalances.

Reduce `max.poll.interval.ms` to a small value to reproduce in a test.

Comment: Hey what is the role of ```max.poll.interval.ms``` ? Does it mean by default its 5 min so if its cost more than 5 min to consume the message it will cause rebalance am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: 5 min to consume here means to process all the message from the batch or a single message?

Comment: All the messages from the last poll - as I said, you can reduce the batch size with `max.poll.records`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, irrespective of ack-mode it is never guaranteed that a message is consumed just once. For instance, A rebalance can happen between the time a message is consumed and the time offset is committed, resulting in Kafka delivering the message again to the newly assigned consumer. It is the applications responsibility to be **idempotent** to duplicated messages.

In order to listen for rebalance events an implementation of [ConsumerRebalanceListener](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html) is needed. You can plug this implementation to Spring's auto configured [ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.html) instance. A more detailed description of how this can be done has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541369/7652010).

If you wish to create a forced rebalance for testing you can do so by killing one of hopefully more than 1 existing consumers. If using spring-kafka you can do this by using an `@Autowired` instance of `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` and kill/rest/(re)start any consumer. Something on this should do:

```
@Autowired
KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

public void myTest() {
    Collection<MessageListenerContainer> containers = registry.getAllListenerContainers()
    containers.get(0).stop()
}
```

Comment: thankyou @Akhil Bojedla how can I control this issue of Kafka delivering the message again to the newly assigned consumer can you give a small coding example ConsumerRebalanceListener so that i can take it forward that will help me the most

Comment: As mentioned this should be handled within your consumer. It is a common pattern with event driven system. Unfortunately it's hard to give a code sample as making an idempotent system is specific to individual use case. However you can lookup for some common high-level patterns of making applications  idempotent. I'm sure a quick google search of idempotent consumer patterns should throw up some well written articles.

Comment: Hey what is the role of ```max.poll.interval.ms``` ? Does it mean by default its 5 min so if its cost more than 5 min to consume the message it will cause rebalance am i right ?