# Kafka concurrent consumers and partitions assigned

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using kafka to deliver events to our micro service.  We populate/utilize the "key" field to ensure events with the same key are put in the same partition and processed sequentially.  We have also configured consumer concurrency giving birth to many listener containers within a single micro service instance.  recently while testing we saw 5 out of the 6 listener containers processing events with the same key.
[image]
(here we see the listenerContainer- <0,1,2,3,4> all processing an event with the same key.  the breakpointer were conditional on the key)

I have seen [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541369/530933) ([or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284186/530933)) recommend creation of a ConsumerRebalanceListener

Is it really necessary to manually handle partition assignment when using consumer concurrency?

using keys to maintain partition assignment seems like default behavior why would it need to be re-written?

some updates and replies to comments...

How we set consumer concurrency (in our factory):

```
/**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public <T> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, T> listenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, T> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerJsonProperties()));
        factory.setConcurrency(kp.getConsumerConcurrency());
        return factory;
    }
```

I did double check the topics for producing issue.
The key (a uuid) does show up in 2 different partitions (out of 12 total), however one topic only has older events while the other has all the newer events for this key.  So it seems to be working as expected, I just think the key moved topics at some point.

Comment: How did you setup your consumer concurrency? Also, did you check if these records belong to the same partition? (they should because same key—but maybe there is an issue with the producer?)

Comment: The Javadoc for the rebalance listener explains it gives you more direct control over offset storage, and a final chance to commit, or place to seek, which is especially useful if you do not depend on Kafka for that offset storage. In any case, multiple listeners shouldn't be assigned the same partition (to process the same key), but multiple threads can be started from a consumer poll batch to process offsets from one partition in parallel. https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

Comment: @StéphaneD. i updated the question to answer your questions..

Comment: @OneCricketeer "multiple threads can be started from a consumer poll batch to process offsets from one partition in parallel."  looking at the screenshot above those look like different listener container threads; do you agree?  what would it look like if they were consumer parallel threads

Comment: a key does not move between partitions (the whole Kafka ecosystem is built on this concept). This can happen only if you've added partitions manually (which is very rarely the case). Is that the case? If not, how are produced your records? (language, framework)

Comment: afaik we have not added any partitions manually (we use julie).  we use the eventKafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, event);

Comment: I don't have experience with spring-kafka, in particular, but assume you polled 100 records, and set concurrency as 4. This may try to distribute 25 records to be processed by each thread... Depending on your records, this may result in bad order or race-conditions. If that's not what you want, then you may not want to use the concurrent listener, and rather simply run 4 instances of your Spring process, each with one consumer KafkaListener thread

Comment: Regarding your update, keys cannot move topics unless the producer code was explicitly sending it to each; did you mean partition?

Comment: ya sorry guys after investigation the number of partitions changed, likely causing the same key to end up in multiple partitions.  today we have deleted and recreated that topic so hopefully that will resolve that

Comment: thank you all for your comments.  i believe this was caused from a completely  different topic resulting in the same object being updated concurrently.  there was some other issues with keys in the partition, but recreating the topic fixed that.